# Search/Find a file and file content in Hadoop

Tags: file, filesystems, hadoop, distributed, distributed-computing

I am currently working on a project using Hadoop DFS.

1. I notice there is no search or find command in Hadoop Shell. Is there a way to search and find a file (e.g. testfile.doc) in Hadoop DFS?
2. Does Hadoop support file content search? If so, how to do it? For example, I have many Word Doc files stored in HDFS, I want to list which files have the words "computer science" in them.

What about in other Distributed File Systems? Is file content search a soft spot of distributed file systems?

Comment: I answered in another post(https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-index-and-search-files-in-HDFS) proposing a software to index all file names in hdfs named Schemaindex. The software is built on python and adminlte(js). This index software also leverage inotify feature from HDFS to monitor hdfs in real time. The project is here on github: schemaindex (https://github.com/qiyangduan/schemaindex) If anyone wants to try it, you can install it by:
$ pip install schemaindex
$schemaindex runserver
Then you can create a data source and “reflect” the data source. Disclaimer: I am the auther and

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. You can do this: `hdfs dfs -ls -R / | grep [search_term]`.
2. It sounds like a MapReduce job might be suitable here. [Here's](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Grep) something similar, but for text files. However, if these documents are small, you may run into inefficiencies. Basically, each file will be assigned to one map task. If the files are small, the overhead to set up the map task may be significant compared to the time necessary to process the file.

Comment: Maybe I should also mention, Lucene (http://lucene.apache.org/) can do indexing and search, and I think there is a plugin for Word docs. You can probably rig something together. I think there has been some work done on Lucene + Hadoop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Isnt hadoop dfs -lsr / | grep [search_term] very slow against many files or directories?

Comment: It's definitely not fast, but it isn't too bad. On our cluster, with >100,000 files, it still takes less than a minute, which I think is pretty acceptable.

Comment: @@ajduff574  I assume resursive list lsr command does not use any map/reduce function to do the search right? Why doesn't hadoop support the search in metadata level? As all the metadata is stored in Namenode's RAM right?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [hadoop.HdfsFindTool](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/search_hdfsfindtool.html) with solr, is more quickly than 'hdfs dfs ls -R' and more useful.

```
hadoop jar search-mr-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool -find /user/hive/tmp -mtime 7

Usage: hadoop fs [generic options]
    [-find <path> ... <expression> ...]
    [-help [cmd ...]]
    [-usage [cmd ...]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how the data is stored in HDFS, you may need to use the -text option to dfs for a string search.  In my case I had thousands of messages stored daily in a series of HDFS sequence files in AVRO format. From the command-line on an edge node, this script:

1. Searches the /data/lake/raw directory at its first level for a list
   of files.
2. Passes result to awk, which outputs columns 6 & 8 (date and file
   name)
3. Grep outputs lines with the file date in question (2018-05-03)
4. Passes those lines with two columns to awk, which outputs only column 2,
   the list of files.
5. That is read with a while-loop which takes each file name, extracts
   it from HDFS as text.
6. Each line of the file is grep-ed for string "7375675".
7. Lines meeting that criteria are output the screen (stdout)

There is a solr jar-file implementation that is supposedly faster I have not tried.

```
hadoop fs -ls /data/lake/raw | awk {'print $6"   "$8'} | grep 2018-05-03 | awk {'print $2'} | while read f; do hadoop fs -text $f | grep 7375675 && echo $f ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I'm searching for files in hadoop, as stated by ajduff574, it's done with

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R $path | grep "$file_pattern" | awk '{print $8}'
```

This code simply print out the path for each pattern and can then be further be manipulated incase you wish to search within the content of the files. Ex:

```
hdfs dfs -cat $(hdfs dfs -ls -R $path | grep "$file_pattern" | awk '{print $8}') | grep "$search_pattern"
```

search_pattern:
The content that you are looking for within the file

file_pattern:
The file that you are looking for.

path:
The path for the search to look into recursivly, this includes sub folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you can search like this:

```
hadoop -find . -name "<name_of_file>"
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- There is a find command on HDFS called `-find` for your first example this works:

```
hdfs dfs -find /some/path/ -name "testfile.doc"
```

2.- For the content search I would suggest list the files and save the result in a file

```
  hdfs dfs -ls -R /some/path/ >> someFile
```

and then just put some filters on that file like:

```
  cat someFile | grep "computer science"
```

And you will get your result.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old topic, but as I came across it I'd like to share my knowledge.

The mapReduce job **org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep** can be used for this purpose:

Hadoop's [Grep](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/Grep.html)

```
hadoop org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep
Grep <inDir> <outDir> <regex> [<group>]
Generic options supported are
-conf <configuration file>     specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>            use value for given property
-fs <local|namenode:port>      specify a namenode
-jt <local|resourcemanager:port>    specify a ResourceManager
-files <comma separated list of files>    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
-libjars <comma separated list of jars>    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
-archives <comma separated list of archives>    specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.

The general command line syntax is
bin/hadoop command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems there it does not output the actual files which contained the search term, so it is probably not really helpful in your case.